# Strip out char and special chars to get number

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a JSON part of my code which saves to the database like so:

```
 Bare Filter - £200.00
```

But I want to know how to strip everything out and just get the number so it's 20000 for example.

Can this be done?

I'm guessing str_replace() might be good, but not sure how to use it to achieve what I need.

Comment: what about the 22 part in the (length=22)?

Comment: That's just showing me the length of chars in the string i did a var_dump() to show this. So it's just this Bare Filter - £200.00 i wan to strip everything else out and just leave the numbers. No matter how long the string.

Comment: It can be done, but how to do it depends on the patterns in the input. Might there be multiple numbers on a line that you want to extract separately?  Do you want to treat `1.00` and `10.0` and `100` the same?  More information about the input would make this question easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str);
```

should leave just the numbers.

Then you could convert the string to a number by doing

```
$number = (int)$str;
```

Comment: Legend worked a treat I knew there was a way, just wasn't sure how! lol

Comment: Now my question is in my Laravel view file i now get 20000 but want it to show has GBP so £200.00 and put the . in the right places

Answer (score 0):

If yout want to keep only the numbers from the string you can do

```
$str = 'Bare Filter - £200.00';

echo preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
```

This will echo 20000.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by getting rid of anything that's not a number using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace), like so:

```
$original = 'Bare Filter - £200.00';
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $original);
```